# dimension reduction of matrix TFIDF

Tags: java, matrix, classification, tf-idf

I  calculate the TFIdf(term frequency,inverse document frequency) and i have seen that after this step it is necessary to reduce the dimension of My Matrix with  using  methods like LSI ,chi -square test...,

I haven't any idea how i can implement chi square test in java for dimensionality reduction  of matrix TFIDF,if there is some library to do this or tutorial in which they explain how i can do this, tell me please

Comment: Are you using a sparse matrix representation?

Comment: hi,
yes larsmans  , i calculated the weight of each term in document ,  for reduction  i am used the method of document frequency and i remove all term : if document frequency <threshold but this methode is  not efficace  now i have a sparse matrix.
please how i can implement the  chi square test  and a Latent semantic indexing in java.
 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to do chi-square; that's not a technique for dimension reduction.

What you want to do is SVD, or singular value decomposition.  That is the technique used in LSI/LSA for dimensionality reduction.

Wikipedia suggests using a library called 'S-Space Pacakage' for LSA in Java.  I haven't used it myself, but you may want to look into it.

http://code.google.com/p/airhead-research/

Answer (score 5):

use gensims library for LSA, LDA.
It can practically perform LSA for any large dataset. It does not load the entire corpus into memory at once but does a lazy read.

Comment: Gensim is terrific, but I believe OP is looking for a Java solution. Gensim is for Python.